# Can we create table for wordpress?

Tags: database, wordpress

I am very new to wordress. I have a appointment form. While submitting a form i need to save those information from the form to the database. I created a table of my own lets say wp_appointment and saved the information to this table. Now what i want to know is that is this a good way to do so or is there any solution to this. And i need to display those information in admin section and update. Is it possible? Please do suggest me if i can do or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is an example for appointment data model: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/hairdressers/index.htm

Comment: is there a reason that you cannot use one of the plugins already that you need to create a table like that? Perhaps you want to be more specific as to why you need to set up this table of your own with wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

> Now what i want to know is that is
>   this a good way to do so or is there
>   any solution to this.

Yes, this is the ideal way to doing this. Besides, there is something to consider:

- For ease of use and compatability, you can use wordpress's built-in database functions. Check this one: [**wpdb Class**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class)

> And i need to display those
>   information in admin section and
>   update. Is it possible?

Sure. You can create a custom admin page and show/make editable them in there. As a start point check this link: [**Adding Administration Menus**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus). You can apply the instructions told there to your function.php file to have custom pages without create an "external plugin".

Comment: Thank you gasoved. Yes i am using the same that you have mentioned. And it works well. The only problem now i am facing is the pagination. I am not being able to use the pagination that exists in wordpress. Once again thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions: Yes, it's possible.  And what you described is being done by current calendar plugins.

Here is one:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-calendar/

I would take a look at their code to see how they implement something similar to your idea.